# Defining a function before strings

Tags: function, python-3.x

Okay so this is the code im testing and it simply doesnt work. Python says my x is not defined even though my set_x should set x to a value. What am I missing?

```
def hi():
    print(x)

def set_x1():
    x = "hello"
    hi()

def set_x2():
    x = "world"
    hi()

set_x1()
set_x2()
```

Comment: There are two `x`s, both local to two functions. You have to declare an `x` variable outside of `hi()`, or pass a parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closer to your original code, just pass the variable:

```
def hi(x):
    print(x)

def set_x1():
    x = "hello"
    hi(x)

def set_x2():
    x = "world"
    hi(x)

set_x1()
set_x2()
```

It's all to do with your hello function not being able to see what's inside the x variable in other functions, which we know as a local variable. Here's a good lecture that tells you what's going on behind the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set x in a [local scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Function_scope). You could return a value instead (and perhaps set `x` to that value):

```
def hi(x_arg):
    print(x_arg)

def x1():
    return "hello"

def x2():
    return "world"

x = x1()
hi(x)
x = x2()
hi(x)
```

In your original code, `x` is no longer defined when the function ends. Since it is **local** to the function's scope.

Another way for a function to affect the "outer world" would be to mutate a mutable object, but that's beyond our scope (see what I did there? :-) ... ).